# how to prevent libraries from modifying the root logger?

Tags: python, logging

Some libraries like `oslo_log` [modify the root logger](http://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/oslo.log/tree/oslo_log/log.py#n227), which completely wipes out my own logging configuration.

To prevent this, I monkey patched the standard logging library like this:

```
def hackyCustomGetLogger(name=None, true_behavior=False):
    """
    a replacement for the logging.getLogger function that returns a fake
    root logger if called with name=None and true_behavior=False.

    this is to prevent third party libraries from altering the root logger
    configuration.
    """
    if name:
        return logging.Logger.manager.getLogger(name)
    else:
        if true_behavior:
            return logging.root
        # if no name is specified, and `true_behavior` is not forced to True,
        # we return a fake logger
        warning = ('you called an altered version of logging.getLogger, '
                   'that returns a fake root logger. see {} ({})')
        logging.root.warning(warning.format(__name__, __file__))
        return logging.RootLogger(logging.WARNING)

logging.getLogger = hackyCustomGetLogger
```

It works, but eww... monkey patching the python standard library sounds like a *very* bad idea. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Libraries should not be attempting to modify the logging setup. I consider that a bug myself.

I note that the example you quoted only does the setup if there is no root_logger already configured:

```
# Sometimes logging occurs before logging is ready (e.g., oslo_config).
# To avoid "No handlers could be found," temporarily log to sys.stderr.
root_logger = logging.getLogger(None)
if not root_logger.handlers:
    root_logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
```

So maybe a better work around is to make sure that there are loggers already defined?